# Efficient implementation of a "constant" Set ADT

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, set

I need to implement a "constant" set. That is, a data structure that only supports membership test. Additionally (of course), I need a factory routine that, given a list of elements, constructs a constant set.

Notice that not only is mutation not allowed on the constant set, but additionally I don't need an "add" operation that returns a new constant set (that is, once initialization takes place, I'm only interested in testing whether an element is in the set or not).

Goold old hash tables are an obvious choice here, but I wonder, can we somehow take advantage of the fact that we need to support only a single operation (and, when constructing the set, we know what all its elements will be)? Is there a data structure (a specialized type of hash table, perhaps) that would perform particularly well here?

Comment: [Perfect hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) perhaps ?

Comment: What sort of Big O are you looking for? Constant time?

Comment: @Justin: yeah, constant time. But it goes beyond that: we can already get O(1) with "regular" hash tables? Can we do better, not asymptotically, but in practice (by having a lower constant, better cache locality, etc.)?

Comment: @abeln OK, a hash table with an initial capacity should wield good numbers. It's no longer amortized cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Alexandre C. mentioned in a comment, this is an excellent spot to use a perfect hash table. A perfect hash table is a hash table that uses a hash function that guarantees no collisions among its elements. There are various schemes for accomplishing this; one of the most common and simplest options is to use the [FKS perfect hash table](http://theory.stanford.edu/~matias/papers/fks.pdf), which uses a two-layer hash table. It guarantees worst-case O(1) membership tests and is extremely efficient in practice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `gperf` is a thing, too.

Answer (score 1):

From a theoretical standpoint, it doesn't get any faster than the O(1) of a hashtable, simply because O(1) is the fastest there is (except avoiding doing anything at all, which is O(0) ;)).

If your hashtable is very large (so that it has to be stored on disk, or even distributed across multiple machines), a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) can give you a fast probabilistic test for membership.

It is possible that a bloom filter is even worthwhile for in-memory sets, if the filter is small enough to fit in a L1 cache line so you don't have to hit main memory, but that's probably a premature optimization.

Comment: I understand that the asymptotic lower bound of hash tables is optimal. I'm not even opposed to hash tables. The question is, can I *somehow* take advantage of my additional constraints to build a data structure (a specific type of hash table, perhaps) that works particularly well here?

Comment: Hence the next two paragraphs ;)

Comment: Sorry, should've read it more carefully. I like the bloom filter idea (i.e. that it might fit in a cache line). However, my sets are not likely to be very large, and they will certainly fit in RAM. I guess I'm getting specific enough that the solution will be to try something and profile it.

Comment: If the set is small, a great hash set implementation is available in Guava's ImmutableSet (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained). It's very instructive to look at the source code  for the immultable set.